# How can I convert a string into a unicode character?

Tags: javascript, unicode

In Javascript `'\uXXXX'` returns in a unicode character. But how can I get a unicode character when the `XXXX` part is a variable?

For example:

```
var input = '2122';
console.log('\\u' + input);             // returns a string: "\u2122"
console.log(new String('\\u' + input)); // returns a string: "\u2122"
```

The only way I can think of to make it work, is to use `eval`; yet I hope there's a better solution:

```
var input = '2122';
var char = '\\u' + input;
console.log(eval("'" + char + "'"));    // returns a character: "™"
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) like this: `String.fromCharCode(parseInt(input,16))`. When you put a Unicode value in a string using `\u`, it is interpreted as a hexdecimal value, so you need to specify the base (16) when using `parseInt`.

Comment: Thanks for linking me to `fromCharCode()`, but this still doesn't convert `2122` into a trademark sign

Comment: `parseInt(input, 16)` seems to do the job ;)

Comment: I guess you want the base to be passed to `parseInt` instead of `fromCharCode`.

Answer (score 20):

`String.fromCharCode("0x" + input)`

or

`String.fromCharCode(parseInt(input, 16))` as they are 16bit numbers (UTF-16)

Answer (score 12):

[JavaScript uses UCS-2 internally.](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding)

Thus, `String.fromCharCode(codePoint)` won’t work for supplementary Unicode characters. If `codePoint` is `119558` (`0x1D306`, for the `''` character), for example.

If you want to create a string based on a non-BMP Unicode code point, you could use [Punycode.js](http://mths.be/punycode)’s utility functions to convert between UCS-2 strings and UTF-16 code points:

```
// `String.fromCharCode` replacement that doesn’t make you enter the surrogate halves separately
punycode.ucs2.encode([0x1d306]); // ''
punycode.ucs2.encode([119558]); // ''
punycode.ucs2.encode([97, 98, 99]); // 'abc'
```

Answer (score 11):

Since ES5 you can use

> String.fromCodePoint(number)

to get unicode values bigger than 0xFFFF.

So, in every new browser, you can write it in this way:

```
var input = '2122';
console.log(String.fromCodePoint(input));
```

or if it is a hex number:

```
var input = '2122';
console.log(String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(input, 16)));
```

More info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint

### Edit (2021):

*fromCodePoint* is not just used for bigger numbers, but also to combine Unicode emojis.
For example, to draw a waving hand, you have to write:

```
String.fromCodePoint(0x1F44B);
```

But if you want a waving hand with a skin tone, you have to combine it:

```
String.fromCodePoint(0x1F44B, 0x1F3FC);
```

In future (or from now), you will even be able to combine 2 emoji to create a new one, for example a heart and a fire, to create a burning heart:

```
String.fromCodePoint(0x2764, 0xFE0F, 0x200D, 0x1F525);
```

```html
32-bit number:
<script>
document.write(String.fromCodePoint(0x1F44B));
</script>
<br>
32-bit number + skin:
<script>
document.write(String.fromCodePoint(0x1F44B, 0x1F3FE));
</script>
<br>
32-bit number + another emoji:
<script>
document.write(String.fromCodePoint(0x2764, 0xFE0F, 0x200D, 0x1F525));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var hex = '2122';
var char = unescape('%u' + hex);

console.log(char);
```

will returns " ™ "