# Convert an integer to hexadecimal escape sequence

Tags: javascript

How can I convert an integer to hexadecimal escape sequence format:

```
a = 1;
```

to Expected result:

```
b = '\x00\x00\x00\x01';
```

any idea ?

Comment: I think \x00\x00\x00\x01 is not the unicode code of 1. If I remember well, the rightmost byte should be the ascii code, which is 0x31.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a string into a unicode character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063255/how-can-i-convert-a-string-into-a-unicode-character)

Comment: See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block).

Comment: to me it's still unclear what your result should represent. If it's the string represented for that charcode, then where would the three null-bytes come from? Or do you mean the number 1 in hex-representation? that would be `0x00000001` or simply `0x1`

Comment: Please don't stack questions, create a new post for each question.

Comment: Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution (assuming I understand your question properly) :

```js
var dInput = document.getElementById("d");
var xInput = document.getElementById("x");
var pInput = document.getElementById("p");
var uInput = document.getElementById("u");
var cInput = document.getElementById("c");

dInput.onchange = onChange;
dInput.onkeyup = onChange;
dInput.onclick = onChange;
dInput.onchange();

function onChange () {
  var d = parseInt(this.value, 10); // decimal
  var x = d.toString(16).toUpperCase(); // hexadecimal
  var p = "00000000".slice(x.length) + x; // padded
  var u = p.replace(/([0-9a-f]{2})/gi, "\\x$1"); // unicode
  xInput.value = x;
  pInput.value = p;
  uInput.value = u;
  cInput.value = String.fromCharCode(d);
};
```

```html
<p>Try 10, 49, 65 and 97.</p>
<input id="d" type="number" min="0" step="1" value="1"> decimal
<br><input id="x" type="text" disabled> hexadecimal
<br><input id="p" type="text" disabled> padded
<br><input id="u" type="text" disabled> unicode
<br><input id="c" type="text" disabled> character
```

Comment: `\xXX` is a hexadecimal escape sequence, unicode is `\uXXXX` so `var u = "\\u" + x.padStart(4,0)`

Comment: @Thomas I've read (perhaps mistakenly) "unicode" as "a set of four bytes". Therefore, I think it's better not to change anything. Thanks for the feedback anyway, I didn't notice the ambiguity :-)