# insert unicode like \u1d6fc in a javascript text string

Tags: javascript, unicode, italic

I'm writing some code that scans a string for TeX-style Greek character (like \Delta or \alpha), and replaces the string with the Unicode symbol.  It works fine for the non-italic Greek characters.  The problem is that I want to use mathematical italic for the lower case.  These codes are one digit longer.  For example, the code for the letter alpha is 1d6fc.  When I put \u1d6fc into my string it displays as the character that matches \u1d6f (a lower case m with a superimposed tilde) followed by the letter c.  How do I force the "correct" reading of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use UTF-16 [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_from_U+010000_to_U+10FFFF) for characters beyond the UTF-16 range. In your particular case, you can use 0xD835 0xDEFC:

```js
    console.log('\uD835\uDEFC')
```

[Here is a handy pair calculator.](http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/SurrogatePairCalculator.htm) If you don't have to worry about Internet Explorer, you can also use `String.fromCodePoint()`, which will deal with that mess for you. If you *do* have to worry about Internet Explorer, [MDN has a polyfill for that method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint#Polyfill).

Comment: Awesome!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

To produce a `\u` escape sequence with more than 4 hex digits (code point belonging to a so-called astral plane), you can use the [Unicode code point escape](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode-code-point) notation `\u{xxxxx}`:

```js
console.log ('\u{1d6fc}');
```

or you can call [String.fromCodePoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) with the code point value expressed in hexadecimal using the `0x` prefix notation:

```js
console.log (String.fromCodePoint (0x1d6fc));
```

Comment: [`String.fromCodePoint` is not perfect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9112856/4441984).